# Добавление badge к пункту bottomNavigationView android

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

Есть необходимость добавлять индикатор в item bottomNavigationView. Для этого я сделал разметку badge:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_badge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

и из активности я добавляю информацию в textView:

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(0);

notificationBadge = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, menuView, false);
TextView textView = notificationBadge.findViewById(R.id.counter_badge);

textView.setText("15");

itemView.addView(notificationBadge);
```

но у меня выбирается только один элемент менюшки, а мне нужно несколько счетчиков добавлять. Я думал что изменив значение getChildAt() я получу доступ к разным пунктам, но у меня вылезает ошибка которая указывает на `BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(0)`:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet/de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.screens.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference
```

думал что можно по id это сделать, но не получилось и вышла та же ошибка. Как еще можно получить доступ и отправить данные сразу в несколько элементов менюшки?

Comment: @woesss, не очень понимаю что вы имеете в виду, почему не присваиваивается значение, если я выбираю item

Comment: @woesss, да провтыкал указать на какой строке вылетает, сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственный возможный вариант:

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
BottomNavigationItemView itemView = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(1);
View notificationBadge = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, menuView, false);
TextView textView = notificationBadge.findViewById(R.id.counter_badge);
textView.setText(sp.getString("new_receivedM",""));
itemView.addView(notificationBadge);

BottomNavigationItemView itemView1 = (BottomNavigationItemView) menuView.getChildAt(2);
View notificationBadgeOne = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.notification_badge, menuView, false);
TextView textView_1 = notificationBadgeOne.findViewById(R.id.counter_badge);
textView_1.setText(sp.getString("all_jobs",""));
itemView1.addView(notificationBadgeOne);
```

сколько нужно бейджев, столько создаете из программно. Согласен что это ооочень кривой метод, но он работает.